# Android Opening Another activity by clicking the button

Tags: android

I have an application which has 1 home page and main activity. I have a button on the home screen by clicking this I want to pass to main activity. How can I do that?

Comment: Read up on intents

Answer (score 0):

```
    btnDemo= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDemo);   

    btnDemo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btnDemo= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDemo);   

btnDemo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```